# Allow moderators to manually ban >2k users from suggesting edits to tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, moderator-tools, tag-wiki, edit-ban

I recently found a guy mass-plagiarizing tag wikis. The problem is, he had more than 2,000 reputation and thus a moderator couldn't manually ban him from suggesting edits.

This manual ban is useful for just making someone stop what they're doing *now*, so we can pick up the pieces, regroup, and send a 'real' message to them later.

So, my request: Allow moderators to manually ban users with >2000 reputation from suggesting edits, just like we can with users <2000 reputation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's no UI for this, but the functionality exists. Drop this into your console, fill in the userID, optionally adjust the days to be banned, and it's done.

```
$.post("/admin/ban-suggested-edits", {userId:whateverUserId, days:4, fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey})
```

If this is commonly-needed, we could probably enable it in the normal UI; we omitted it originally to avoid confusion (this won't block *any other edits* from users with editing privileges).

Comment: Planning to join the dev team soon? ;)

Comment: @Sha looks like Shog has just got that hacking is a pretty interesting thing to do ;D

Comment: good grief... Y'all know I did this stuff *before* I got hired here, right?